# Is it possible to DECLARE and SET in the same statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

New to Transact-SQL, I know the following is the usual way to DECLARE, then SET a variable:

```
DECLARE @strDBName  NVARCHAR(50)
SET @strDBName  = N'MY_DB'
```

I am wondering whether it is possible to do this in a single statement (just like in many other programming languages), something like:

```
DECLARE @strDBName  NVARCHAR(50) = N'MY_DB'
```

Is this supported in T-SQL?

Comment: answer is yes, but was that so hard to test ?

Comment: @Withheld Done, have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid syntax:

```
DECLARE @strDBName NVARCHAR(50) = N'MY_DB'
```

It can be tested by a simple `PRINT (@strDBName)` statement.